# Why this isn't this AJAX function changing color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

What I'm trying to do is I have glyphicon box and if there's a notification I want the box to change its color with the count of the notification. I think I'm almost there but it just won't work. I inspected, but CSS doesn't come through. So here's what I did.

I have this in navbar

```
  <li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle notification-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" id="button">
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-inbox' aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id='notification_dropdown'>

              </ul>
            </li>
```

So glyphicon-inbox needs to change its color with the count.

To achieve that I have this code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".notification-toggle").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "{% url 'get_notifications_ajax' %}",
          data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
          },
         success: function(data){
            $("#notification_dropdown").html(' <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Notifications</li>');
            var count = data.count
            console.log(count)
            if (count == 0) {
                  $("#notification_dropdown").removeClass('notification');
              var url = '{% url "notifications_all" %}'
              $("#notification_dropdown").append("<li><a href='" + url+ "'>View All Notifications</a></li>")
            } else {
                  $("#notification_dropdown").addClass('notification');
              $(data.notifications).each(function(){
                var link = this;
                $("#notification_dropdown").append("<li>" + link + "</li>")
              })
            }
            console.log(data.notifications);
          },
          error: function(rs, e) {
            console.log(rs);
            console.log(e);
          }
        })
      })
    })
    </script>
```

if notification count == 0, I have

```
$("#notification_dropdown").removeClass('notification');
```

else

```
          $("#notification_dropdown").addClass('notification');
```

And for CSS I have this

```
#notification_dropdown{
}

#notification_dropdown.notification{
  background-color: red;
}
```

As you see the color should be red but it doesn't do the trick. I think I need to place #button that's for glyphicon-box somewhere but I don't know. Also, I'm not sure how to make count appear in the box.

If I use `$("#notification_dropdown")` in console I get

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu notification" role="menu" id="notification_dropdown"> <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Notifications</li><li><a href="/notifications/164/?next=/post/test0/">content</a></li><li><a href="/notifications/165/?next=/post/test0/">content</a></li></ul>
```

I'm trying to make it like Stack Overflow, the notification box changing color with the count on it - is this possible?

Comment: Use `dataType: 'json'` in `$.ajax` configuration options or manually parse the string to JSON using `JSON.parse()` in the `success` callback.

Comment: do you get value for console.log(count).. .?

Comment: have you checked if data.count has any value. Also try to change your css to only .notification instead of #notification_dropdown.notification

Comment: @Tushar can you show that in the answer?I'll try that definitely

Comment: @DemoUser yes I see the count...just don't know how to display

Comment: @user2181397 no difference

Answer (score 0):

to change the color of a glyphicon - you need to change the color property not the background:

```
#notification_dropdown.notification{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: well that is the way to change the color of the glyhicon - it must be the selectors you are using or the logic to determine class. try adding this style rule as an inline style rule to the glyphicon to confirm the colour change then work backward to work out how to select it / modiufy it

Comment: hmm thank you...I tried that...trying to wrap my head around like that but failed so I posted here actually :)...

Comment: note that "#notification_dropdown.notification will not target the glyphicon because it is not a part of the notification_dropdown - it sits above it so must be targeted directly, or as a descendant of "#button" or as a sibling of the notification_dropdown.

Comment: so I should set id on glyphicon and target that?

Comment: you could - or you could use "#button span", but that would get both the glypicon and the chevron - so you could youse :first... or put an id / class on the glypicon

Answer (score 0):

Is there any element exist with the same id 'notification_dropdown' in entire html? Please inspect html and find by this Id. It may be in the hidden form. In that case there may be chances the css is getting applied to that hidden element instead of this visible element.

and if yes then try:

```
$("#notification_dropdown:visible").removeClass('notification');
```

or

```
$("#notification_dropdown:visible").addClass('notification');
```

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $("#notification_dropdown:visible").addClass('notification');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Do you get any error in console? ajax response is coming properly?

Comment: no I just don't get any css or anything....nothing's changed...my guess was I should've set id to notification box(glyphicon itself but this doens't do it either)

Comment: thank you but seriously I don't know what's going on I don't get any error or anything..

Comment: unfortunately not, it does nothing...hmm....really not sure what I should do... maybe I should create a new icon that shows up when notification is there....